# How to use microsoft UDDI 3 and its SDK and API

Tags: api, uddi

I want a tutorial or document that describe API functions of microsoft UDDI, and how to find services from it. their functions and its input and output parameters in C#

Comment: i found some solutions to work with it base on try and error. if anyone need this ask me to make a clean version of it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you are required to use the Microsoft API or not, but jUDDI has a .NET web service client.

It might be worth checking out and there are a number of examples.
http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/juddi/trunk/juddi-client.net/